# Is there a better way to design this DynamoDB table that doesn't require duplication of data?

Tags: database-design, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I have a relatively simple data model that I want to store in DynamoDB.  However, because of the different access patterns, choosing the primary and sort keys has been difficult.  I've found a way to store the data in a way that fits my patterns, but requires multiple rows with essentially the same data.  This makes me feel like I'm missing something.

**The scenario:**
The application manages records for our customers who have large amounts of IOT devices reporting their states consistently over time.

**The Data:**

```
customer_id, device_id, timestamp, device_state, device_manufacturer
```

**The Access Patterns:**

1. Get the most recent record for each of the unique `device_id` values associated with a `customer_id`.
2. Get the most recent records for a `customer_id` regardless of `device_id`
3. Get `timestamp` sorted values for a specific `device_id`, `customer_id` pair.

Point 2 and 3 together seems straightforward at first.  A table where the primary key is `customer_id` and a sort key of `timestamp`, with a GSI where the primary key is `device_id` and a sort key of `timestamp`.  With this set up I don't know how I would achieve point 1 without a very costly scan and filter operation on the table.  I expect the table to get to be very large.

**My solution**

```
| primary key                      | sort key         |
| -------------------------------- | ---------------- |
| "customer_" + customer_id        | timestamp        |
| "device_" + device_id            | timestamp        |
| "latest_device_" + customer_id   | device_id        |
```

Each device record gets updated 3 times with the different key strategies.  A new record is created with the first and second keys, and the row is updated for the third.  Point 1 above uses the "latest_device_" + customer_id key, Point 2 uses the "customer_" + customer_id, and Point 3 uses the "device_" + device_id key.

This works, but feels gross.  It makes me think I'm missing a core concept for Dynamo or some other key point that would make me not have to duplicate data.

**Is there a way to design my table to avoid this duplication of data while still allowing me to achieve the 3 access patterns?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First rule of nosql design...duplication is expected.

Secondly, with DDB you don't have to always do the duplication yourself.  DDB will do it for you via Global Secondary Indexes (GSI).

Third rule, know your access requirements.  (Good job!)

Here's what I'd consider (assuming no two timestamps for cust/dev are the same)
**table**
hash-key : "customerId#deviceId"
sort-key : "2021-07-08T15:55:34Z"
attributes: {customer_id, device_id, timestamp, device_state, device_manufacturer}

**And a GSI with**
hash: customer_id
sort: timestamp

That would cover
2. Get the most recent records for a customer_id regardless of device_id
--> Query(gsi,hk="customerId")
3. Get timestamp sorted values for a specific device_id, customer_id pair.
--> Query(table,hk="customerId#deviceId")

**The tricky one is**

1. Get the most recent record for each of the unique device_id values associated with a customer_id.

I'd look having a CUSTOMER record (possibly maintained via DDB streams+lambda)  containing an array of the most recent records for each device for that customer.  Assuming the list is small enough to fit reasonably in a DDB record. Basically considering this as a type of [aggregation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-gsi-aggregation.html) of the actual records.

Comment: You're right about that being the tricky one.  I don't know if your suggestion would work for this use case.  A customer could have < 10k different devices.  

This is initially why my mind went to creating a separate hash key, which in this case would be something along the lines of "customer_id#latest" sorted on device ID.

Comment: yeah, with 10K devices would be hard to fit.  But you could still use streams+lambda to maintain that latest record.